# Docker Toolbox - Looks like something went wrong in step 'Setting env'

Tags: docker, installation, environment-variables

I am trying to install Docker Toolbox on Windows 8.1. I receive this error, "Something went wrong in step 'Setting env' when running the Docker QuickStart terminal.

I have already uninstalled and installed Docker Toolbox and restarting my computer. I have no previous installations of VirtualBox and I have been installing it together with Docker Toolbox only. I only run the Docker QuickStart terminal as administrator.

I found this link on this problem. https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/793

But, I do not understand the step suggested by nPaul. Could someone please explain how to do what nPaul suggested or any other ideas on how to encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0):

nPaul says that comment line

```
      ##eval "$("${DOCKER_MACHINE}" env --shell=bash --no-proxy "${VM}" | sed -e "s/export/SETX/g" | sed -e "s/=/ /g")" &> /dev/null #for persistent Environment Variables, available in next sessions
```

add ## tag to that line and re-run the docker terminal

Answer (score 0):

@Mystery,

The Docker command-line program for Windows runs a script to configure the entire Docker setup on your machine.  The script is called "start.sh" and it is neither PowerShell nor (Windows) CMD/Batch language, but is Bash (Unix/Linux).

Reading the script I'm pretty sure it's buggy, and that's what "nPaul" found.  So his solution was to comment out the line that caused failure.

In the Bash scripting language only a single hash is needed to comment the line, which is how I made it work correctly.

The 'start.sh' script is in the main Docker directory. It is a regular text file, but you will need administrative privileges to modify it.  I found that I could open the file in Visual Studio Code and it would let me save the modified 'start.sh' by prompting me to authorize administrative privileges.

When the Docker command window runs for me, it is using the Bash shell. I don't know if this is how it will work for you, but don't be surprised if you see something other than your usual Windows prompt.